# rsync fails to sync files from server A to server B. Server B has the rsync daemon running

Tags: linux, perl, unix, ssh, rsync

Im trying to rsync via commander product and getting error following error.

Command used is

```
rsync -arv -K -O --no-perms --delete --exclude=.svn --exclude=.snapshot sourcepath svn@ServerB:/tasks
```

Falling files are not owned by svn user but they are writable by svn user's primary group.

if i try login to serverB as svn user im able to edit these files. Only rsync fails.

WE can't change the ownership of the files as webapp needs to be in different account.

Following is the error message.

```
rsync: mkstemp "/tasks/com/media/.QuerySM.task.Yz4zVg" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/tasks/com/media/.QuerySP.task.eqoVbP" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/tasks/com/media/.QueryST.task.8c1Gsn" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/tasks/com/media/.QueryMW.task.Q18EFI" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/tasks/com/parts/.EFParts.task.0sJVJV" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/tasks/com/parts/.FFModel.task.y6UF1t" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

rsync version

```
   rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30
```

Directory permission is 775.

Interesting thing i found now is it throws this error but it actually copies the file and ends with below error.

```
      sync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rsync - mkstemp failed: Permission denied (13)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039559/rsync-mkstemp-failed-permission-denied-13)

Comment: @Maquefel, solutions didn't help me :-(. I can't make svn user as owner as webapp will fail

Comment: what is your rsync version? And what is your persmission for group for the directory? Can you create new files as svn?

Comment: @Maquefel, added now in the original post. 3.0.6 is the version and 775 is the permission.

Comment: No idea then, you can try elevating http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/rsync-permission-denied-906421/ or you can try adding --in-place option

Comment: Who owns `/tasks/com/{media,parts}` ?

Comment: @ghoti,Owned by webapp account, webapp group which owns that is primary group of svn account.

Comment: And when you say "*Directory permission is 775*", are you referring to just `/tasks/com`, or `media` and `parts` as well?

Comment: @ghoti, task directory permission and all the directories and files underneath got 775 permission.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'svn' user does not have write access to parts of the directory it's responsible for, start by fixing those permission problems. I would guess that the issue is lack of write permission to `/tasks/com` and `/tasks/parts`, so on serverB:

```
chown svn /tasks/com/{media,parts}
```

Next, if you're comfortable with the (serious) security issues with this, you might be able to bypass permission problems by running rsync as root:

```
rsync [other options] --rsync-path="sudo rsync" sourcepath user@serverB:/path/
```

This `--rsync-path` option tells rsync to run rsync as root on remote servers (source or target).  To use this, you will need to set up sudo on serverB so that your user receives no password challenge when trying to run rsync.

BE AWARE THAT THIS IS A RISK.  Rsync can do many things, and granting rights like this pretty much grants root access to anyone who can get a shell on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but sudo access on that server is resticted :-(