# Permission denied (13) when using rsync

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, rsync

I set up rsync on my raspberry pi 2 using this [guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/raspberry-pi-as-backup-server-for-linux-and-windows/).

I am on step "*18. Backup Control File on the Raspberry Pi*", this is the code which is producing the error:

```
if [[ ${now} != ${last} ]]
    then
            # New Month
            mkdir -p "${basePath}/current/"
            rm -Rf "${basePath}/current/"*
            echo "${now}" > "checkMonth.txt"
    fi
```

Im using windows 10 64bit myself. It works fine on my laptop from which I did the setup, but on my desktop it produces the following error.

```
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/home/backupuser/current/***/***" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
```

The script creates folders which cant be accessed by any user on the pi. On the laptop everything still works fine. Also ssh with my desktop works fine, too.

The folders have the rights: ---rwx---

I dont think this question is related to [rsync - mkstemp failed: Permission denied (13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039559/rsync-mkstemp-failed-permission-denied-13) because Im already using ssh and the error message is different.

Comment: What user is running the rsync command? In the linked guide they are running everything as "bu" and you are writing to "backupuser" 's home directory

Comment: The name of my user is "backupuser" and I changed everything in the code accordingly. Everything is working fine on my laptop.